# Cut the stick HackerRank Challenge Lisp implementation

Tags: algorithm, lisp, common-lisp

I am pretty stumped right now. Mind you the struggle has taught me a lot about lisp already. However, I may need a little nudge or guidance at this point.

[Cut the sticks challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks)

You are given N sticks, where each stick is of positive integral length. A cut operation is performed on the sticks such that all of them are reduced by the length of the smallest stick.

Suppose we have 6 sticks of length

5 4 4 2 2 8
then in one cut operation we make a cut of length 2 from each of the 6 sticks. For next cut operation 4 sticks are left (of non-zero length), whose length are

3 2 2 6
Above step is repeated till no sticks are left.

Given length of N sticks, print the number of sticks that are cut in subsequent cut operations.

Input Format 
The first line contains a single integer N. 
The next line contains N integers: a0, a1,...aN-1 separated by space, where ai represents the length of ith stick.

Output Format 
For each operation, print the number of sticks that are cut in separate line.

Constraints 
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 
1 ≤ ai ≤ 1000

So I get all of the sample test cases correct but some others I do not. For example

With an input of:

```
8
8 8 14 10 3 5 14 12
```

They expect an output of

```
8
7
6
4
3
2
```

However my code gives

```
8
7
6
4
2
```

Here is the function I have come up with for now.

```
(defun cut-print (numbers cut-length)

    (let ((x numbers) (y cut-length) (k 0))
        (loop while (> (length x) 0) do
            (tagbody
                ;; subtracting the min value from all list elements
                (setq x (map 'list (lambda (i) (- i y)) x)) 

                ;; Don't print if the list length hasn't changed
                ;; from last iteration
                ;; else save length changes and print
                (cond ((= k (length x)) (go bottom))
                      ((not (= k (length x)))
                        (setq k (length x))
                        (format t "~d~%" k)))

                ;; move to here if nothing is printed to
                ;; stdout during the current iteration
                bottom
                    (setq x (remove-if (lambda (x) (<= x 0)) x))))))
```

What am I overlooking? Depending on the test case it seems that the logic above will skip over a cut operation according to their expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is `y` changing? In your program it is not changing...

Style:

- Get rid of TAGBODY and GO.
- Replace COND with IF.
- What is the use of variables x and y?
- Use descriptive names instead of x, y, i, k.

A simple recursive version:

```
(defun cut (sticks)
  (when sticks
    (print (length sticks))
    (let ((smallest (reduce #'min sticks)))
      (cut (remove-if-not #'plusp
                          (mapcar (lambda (stick)
                                    (- stick smallest))
                                  sticks))))))
```

Another recursive version could look like this:

```
(defun cut (sticks)
  (labels ((%cut (sticks)
             (when sticks
               (print (length sticks))
               (let ((smallest (first sticks)))
                 (%cut (mapcar (lambda (stick)
                                 (- stick smallest))
                               (member smallest (rest sticks)
                                       :test-not #'=)))))))
    (%cut (sort sticks #'<))))
```

or even:

```
(defun cut (sticks)
  (labels ((%cut (sticks length)
             (when sticks
               (print length)
               (let ((prefix-length (or (position (first sticks) sticks
                                                  :test-not #'=)
                                        1)))
                 (%cut (nthcdr prefix-length sticks)
                       (- length prefix-length))))))
    (setf sticks (sort sticks #'<))
    (%cut sticks (length sticks))))
```

A simple LOOP version:

```
(defun cut (numbers)
  (loop with smallest
        while numbers do
        (print (length numbers))
        (setf smallest (reduce #'min numbers)
              numbers (loop for n in numbers 
                            for n1 = (- n smallest)
                            when (plusp n1)
                            collect n1))))
```

Comment: Oh ok i get it now. Initially I thought that the minimum length was static. Ergo the minimum length obtained from the first stick would be the minimum length subtracted until the entire stick was consumed. It makes much more sense if you compute the minimum at each step. Also thanks for the style pointers. I think i overcomplicated things because i don't have a thorough understanding of lisp yet, but what you pointed out helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As a small brain teaser, here is a shorter solution to the problem:

```
(defun sticks (&rest sticks)
  (do ((rest (sort sticks #'<) (remove (car rest) rest)))
      ((null rest))
      (print (length rest))))
```

Edit: I agree with Rainer Joswig, but leave to code unchanged so that his comment still makes sense.

Comment: I would not use a `&rest` argument - but otherwise a nicely short solution.

Comment: Yea I had to remove the &rest in the sticks arguments to get this to work. Nice solution btw. I am not sure why it was there if you are declaring it at the beginning of your do loop. Could you explain?

Comment: I assume 'it' means 'rest', in which case `&rest` - a part of the syntax for lambda lists - has nothing to do with the variable `rest` that is declared and bound in the `do` macro. I suggest reading the chapter on functions of Practical Common Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you complicating the things. Why to use tagbody at all? Here is a simple Common Lisp solution for this so-called challenge. It passes their test.

```
(defun cut (sticks)
  (let ((shortest (reduce #'min sticks)))
    (mapcan (lambda (x) ;; I user mapcan to not traverse list twice
             (let ((res (- x shortest)))
                (when (plusp res) (list res)))) sticks)))

(defun cut-the-sticks (n sticks)
  (if (null sticks)
    nil
    (let ((cutted (cut sticks)))
      (format t "~&~D" n)
      (cut-the-sticks (length cutted) cutted))))

(cut-the-sticks (read)
                (with-input-from-string (in (read-line))
                  (loop :for x = (read in nil nil)
                        :while x :collect x)))
```

Comment: Not `APPLY`, use `REDUCE`. Otherwise you can compute the minimum of lists only up to `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` length.

Comment: You completly right, thank you. I forgot about it. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have very little practice with lisp (can't get hang of cons cells) so I will give solution in python

```py
def cutprint(lst):
    #sort the list
    lst = sorted(lst)
    #let the maxcut so far be the size of first stick
    maxcut = lst[0]
    #get the size of the list
    n = len(lst)

    #submit the initial size of the list
    yield n    
    #Loop over all sticks in the list
    for stick in lst:
        #subtract the current max cut from the stick
        stick -= maxcut
        #if the cut was to little, we have done the maximum cuts possible
        if stick > 0:        
            #Add the remainder of the last cut to maxcut
            maxcut += stick            
            #submit the current value of n
            yield n        
        #Since we are cutting at each iteration, subtract 1 from n
        n -= 1
```

I think the code is pretty self explanatory and it should be easy to understand

Usage:

```
>>> import stick
>>> for k in stick.cutprint([2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 34]):
...     print k
...
14
11
9
6
4
3
1
```